# PHP & JSON Show column data by user

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm currently in the process of relaying the data from a column called "followers_count", in a table called "tbl_users". The site has several users each with their own page. On those pages a person can click a follow button and the follow count is displayed, using JSON. The code works so far except it only shows/updates the data of "followers_count" for the first "userID" in the table. My question is, how would I alter the code so that it knows for each user's page to display their followers_count?

In changes.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.channel.php';

$user_change = new USER();

$seqFollows = $user_change->runQuery("SELECT followers_count FROM tbl_users");
$seqFollows->execute();
$row = $seqFollows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$follow_count = $row['followers_count'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
$array = array('followers_count'=>$follow_count);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

In index.php?id= (the user page template):

```
<div>
  Channel Adds: <div id="follow_count" style="display:inline;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var timer;

timer = setInterval(function() {

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('changes.php', function(data) {
          $('#follow_count').html(data.followers_count);
        });
      });

}, 1 * 1000);

</script>
```

Also in index.php?id=, this is the code that determines whose page I'm currently viewing:

```
$currentID = ( isset( $_GET['id']) && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) ? trim($_GET['id']) : '' ;

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$currentID));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell changes.php what the user ID value is. You will need to modify your index.php file to supply that value. One option is to modify the AJAX call similarly to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('changes.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>', function(data) {
          $('#follow_count').html(data.followers_count);
        });
      });
```

Then your changes.php file will need to get the value of `$_GET['id']` just like index.php.